# How to make Picasso not change current image if failed to load image

Tags: android, image, view, picasso

I am using Picasso for loading images in image view, and in some condition i load different image but if Picasso failed ti load the new image,it use the error image but i want it to leave the previous image

Answer (score 0):

Example code for your case, if you only need to load an image if the load fails you only need to do the .placeholder part

```
    Picasso.get()
                .load(yoururl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.YOURPLACEHOLDER)
                .into(yourimgview, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
   // show img if success
                        yourimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                  // hide or do nothing on error
                            imgProducto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: no ,i don't want to use a placeholder,what i want is to change the image if it image loaded successfully if not ,don't change image because i'm loading multiple pages in one image view